# How to check whether two colors are same using JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

Once use Chrome, `console.log($("#some-element").css("background-color"))`, it returns `rgba(255, 255, 255, 255)`, which means `white`, how I can check whether an element's background color is white?

Comment: FYI `rgba(0,0,0,0)` is black with `0` opacity.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for. Are you running some automated tests?

Comment: White is (255, 255, 255) in RGB

Comment: I just want to check whether an element's background color is white.

Comment: rgb(255, 255, 255) this is white

Comment: I use Chrome, if one element has no clearly defined ```background-color``` attribute, it returns ```rgba(0,0,0,0)``` instead of ```undefined```, then is it dangerous to say an element has no definition of ```background-color``` if ```$("#some-element").css("background-color") == "rgba(0,0,0,0)"``` returns ```true```?

Comment: Worth checking out the answer at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999209/jquery-how-to-get-the-background-color-code-of-an-element

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9CNJz/

Comment: How to check whether an element defined ```background-color```? When use Chrome, it returns ```rgba(0,0,0,0)```, while when use Firefox, it returns ```transparent```.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the code described in [How to get the background color code of an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999209/jquery-how-to-get-the-background-color-code-of-an-element) where the color's form is converted to its code. You could fetch the codes of the colors you would like compare and than compare the codes.

Comment: How to check whether an element defined ```background-color```? When use Chrome, it returns ```rgba(0,0,0,0)```, while when use Firefox, it returns ```transparent```.

Comment: @coderz As discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380431/check-if-background-color-is-undefined I would see what value value is returned for each of the major browsers and hardcode its conversion to an appropriate more value.

Answer (score 0):

In `JS`

```
if (document.getElementById('someElementId').style.backgroundColor == "rgb(255, 255, 255)");
```

In `JQuery`

```
if($('#someElementId').css('background-color')=="rgb(255, 255, 255)")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
if($("#some-element").css('background-color')=="rgb(255, 255, 255)") 
    console.log("White color detected");
```