# getComputedStyle gives "transparent" instead of actual background color

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-color, getcomputedstyle

This was a surprise. The following code does not seem to give me the actual colors on the screen:

```
h1 = document.querySelector("h1");
window.getComputedStyle(h1).color
```

Gives `rgb(0, 0, 0)` which I think is correct. However

```
window.getComputedStyle(h1).backgroundColor
```

gives `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)`. The actual background color I see on the screen is white.

The element I call h1 is visible on the screen. I was expecting to get the actual background color. The value I get above (in rgba) is not wrong, but not very useful either. It just tells me the background is fully transparent - and that is not a color.

How do I get the actual background color in RGB?

Comment: Try to use dom traversal, if current element's bg is transparent then check parent and so on.

Comment: Thanks @Tony, but getComputedStyle should give me exactly that.

Comment: @Leo: Why do you think it should?

Comment: A very good question, @Bergi. I realize now that `background-color` is a bit different from other values since it depends on so many other things than `background-color` of parent elements. Testing on another element, a `<span>`, I get this `rgba(0,0,0,0)` again even though the actual background is yellow. There is no `position`, `float` etc involved. The element is positioned within the box of the containing element that has the CSS yellow background. I can see the reason for the decision of returning `rgba(0,0,0,0)` however.

Comment: But @Bergi, it still prevents me from what I wanted to do. I wanted to get the contrast between the foreground and the background colors so that I could test for this part of accessibility. As things looks now I think this is impossible in javascript.

Comment: Maybe check [How do I detect the inherited background-color of an element using jQuery/JS?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4259815/1048572)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get element color which has no background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022226/how-to-get-element-color-which-has-no-background) (no solution, but very good explanation. Also consider background images or gradients :-).

Comment: For accessibility testing, you could use an external tool (or browser addon?), or [take a screenshot](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4912092/1048572) and analyze that

Comment: Thanks for the link, @Bergi. You can however actually do much better than that and it would be good if there was javascript/DOM support for it. I am just as surprised as BigDave in the question you linked too. The alternative you mention is a hard way if you want to automate this.

Comment: But as you see in [Athari's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17022428/1048572), a dom element might not have a single color, so there's no native function implemented for this (transparent is the correct value). The traversal already mentioned by Tony is probably the simplest way.

Comment: Yes, there could of course be several background colors, images and transient colors. But you can at least catch those cases - i.e. under certain layout assumptions (for example the viewport dimension+scrolling).

Comment: To be more clear: It is a rather simple thing to implement if you are in the position of developing the Chrome Workspace for example.

Answer (score 7):

If you set your background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, `0`) in your css; `getComputedStyle()` will return `transparent` (in some browsers) instead of your rgba value.

Easy fix for this is setting alpha to something higher than 0 for example 
rgba(255, 255, 255, `0.01`); This will return rgba(255, 255, 255, `0.01`)

Comment: the problem is with Firefox :) I wasted all day searching for a reason why getComputedStyle returns transparent instead of rgba

Answer (score 1):

`getComputedStyle(h1)` provides the  css value of element after applied in active stylesheet.

Which means you can get those css value only which applied to particular element in any way.

Eg:- if you applied background for `h1 :RGB{255, 255, 255},` then you will get the background color white in rgb format otherwise not. It does not provide value for html's default style.

To get the value by `getComputedStyle()`, First you should apply this to element.

For more info [**getComputedStyle()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle)

Comment: Hm, thanks, yes, that was what I saw, of course, but how do I get the html default style color values?